# How to display razor checkbox with appropriate skills and get selected checkbox value on post method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, checkbox

I am creating one registration form which contains details like:

```
FullName:Textbox
Email:Textbox
Skills:checkbox playing 
       checkbox dancing
       checkbox programming
```

I want to display my view like this.but only problem i am getting is with my checkbox.

My Model:

```
public class EmployeeModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Fullname { get; set; }
        public List<SelectedSkillsModel> Skills { get; set; }
    } 

public class SelectedSkillsModel
    {
        public bool Selected { get; set; }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

My Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var employeeModel = new EmployeeModel();
            employeeModel.Skills = GetSkills();
            return View(employeeModel);
        }


        private List<SelectedSkillsModel> GetSkills()
        {
            var Skills = new List<SelectedSkillsModel>();
            Skills.Add(new SelectedSkillsModel { Name = "Playing", Id = 1, Selected = false });
            Skills.Add(new SelectedSkillsModel { Name = "Dancing", Id = 2, Selected = false });
            Skills.Add(new SelectedSkillsModel { Name = "Music", Id = 3, Selected = false });
            Skills.Add(new SelectedSkillsModel { Name = "Programming", Id = 4, Selected = false });
            return Skills;
        }
```

This is my View:

```
<fieldset>
            <legend>EmployeeModel</legend>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Fullname)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Fullname)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Fullname)
            </div>

            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
            </div>

//What should i do here to display checkbox with appropraite skills???

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Skills)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @foreach (var item in Model.Skills)
              {
                  @Html.CheckBox();
              }
            </div>
```

When i will submit my registration form then i should get appropriate skills with Id,Selected and Name value in my EmployeeModel model.

**Note:I want to use Only Razor checkbox**

How do i do this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `Html.CheckBoxFor()` use `bool` parameter which `Selected` property in your `SelectedSkillsModel` and use `Html.HiddenFor()` to post the id of the skill this way:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Skills.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Skills[i].Selected , new { id = "sikll_" + i })
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Skills[i].Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Skills[i].Name)
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Skills[i].Name)
}
```

Comment: I am not getting selected skill name on post method

Comment: use hidden field for it as well see edit as well @MariaPithia

Answer (score 1):

You need a `for` loop or a custom `EditorTemplate` for typeof `SelectedSkillsModel`

Using a loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < Model.Skills.Count; i++)
{
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Skills[i].Selected)
  @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Skills[i].Selected)
  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Skills[i].Id)
  ....
}
```

Using an editor template (`/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/SelectedSkillsModel.cshtml`)

```
@model SelectedSkillsModel
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Selected)
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Selected)
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
```

and in the main view

```
@model EmployeeModel
....
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Skills)
```